countdown/countup string timer in showDialog/Dialog
everything is working but just the show dialog or dialog box cannot update the timer or cannot show the updating countdown or count up timer. And I have used just method not classes becuase I want to show the timer in front of all widgets in the screen.
here is the code:
void showFrostedGlassBox(BuildContext context, String timer) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // Allows dismissing by tapping outside
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Center(child: testing(timer, context),);
    },
  );
}

Widget testing(String timer, BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
               ...
            ),
        child: Text(
                  timer,
                  style: TextStyle(
                              ...
                ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // close button
     
    ],
  );
}

some data exists but not working in this case.

This question is similar to: How to refresh an AlertDialog in Flutter?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Where is your setState() ?
